# Committing data added from Windows Form with Textboxes bound to dataview?

Tags: vb.net, dataview

This is my first post here so forgive me if I break rules and need to clarify some things later. My problem is that I am using Visual Basic 2008 and have a windows form that has several textboxes bound to a dataview. I am able to edit the data just fine and the data is committed to the SQL 2005 express database. Also, I am able to add a record that persists as long as I don't exit the program. Once I edit the new record is lost. So, basically, edits are being committed but additions are not. Here's the code that I am using. Thanks for your time and consideration.

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

  Try
    cn = New SqlConnection(sConnString)
    cn.Open()

    ' Open the Master table
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CAMaster;", cn)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Master")
    dv = New DataView(ds.Tables("Master"))
    cm = CType(Me.BindingContext(dv), CurrencyManager)
    dv.AllowNew = True
    dv.AllowEdit = True
    dv.AllowDelete = True

    ' Bind the form Textboxes to the Master table dataview and assign formatting
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Controls
      If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
        If ctl.Tag <> "" Then
          Select Case ctl.Tag
            Case "Date"
              ctl.DataBindings.Add("Text", dv, ctl.Tag, True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, False, "MM/dd/yyyy")
            Case Else
              ctl.DataBindings.Add("Text", dv, ctl.Tag, True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, False, "C2")
          End Select
        End If
      End If
    Next

  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Form Load Error")
    End
  End Try

  Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click
  Try
    dv.RowFilter = ""
    dv.AddNew()
  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add Error")
  End Try
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOk_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOk.Click
  Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

  Dim i As Integer

  Try
    Me.Validate()
    cm.EndCurrentEdit()
    cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Update(ds, "Master")
    ds.Tables("Master").AcceptChanges()

  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
  End Try

  SetButtons(True)

  If mbAddNewFlag Then
    Me.cmbDate.SelectedItem = Me.txtDate.Text
  End If

  Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was causing my problem. I had the Date textbox inside a container. To access a textbox inside a container you have to reference it differently. So it was never being databound to the textbox. To fix my issue, I moved the textbox ouside the container and the code in my original post worked. What I don't understand is why I wasn't getting an exception when I tried to update the dataset. But, then again, there's a lot about VB.net I don't understand.